# How to binary serialize a class in a Portable Class Library?

Tags: asp.net, session-state, portable-class-library

I'm using a Portable Class Library in my asp.net application and when deploying to Azure my session state needs to be serialized. Classes from this PCL don't have the SerializableAttribute sinds that's not available in the framework subset. Can't I put these classes in the ASP.NET session?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can use one of the available 3rd party serializers that are available for the Portable Class Library:

- [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) - binary
- [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Both are available on [NuGet](http://nuget.org)

Comment: Which would mean that I'd have to write my own session state provider, or how would I make the Azure State Provider use my custom serializer?

Comment: You can also serialize your class and convert it into a string and insert the string into the session. Another option is to write your own session state provider that is using your custom serializer.

Comment: @dna +1 for Json.NET. And regarding your comment *"convert it into a string and insert the string into the session"*, I found the following article helpful in terms of *where* to put such logic: [Work Around Your ASP.Net Session Serialization Issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/schlepticons/archive/2008/08/24/work-around-your-asp-net-session-serialization-issues.aspx). i.e. do the adapting in `Application_PostAcquireRequestState()` and `Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute()`.